# AWS ROSA Cluster Build - image-registry is not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

We have been trying to deploy a cluster into our AWS STS for a couple of weeks now, most of the issues have been around the networking side, and the company's implementation of specific tf codesets. Like whitelisting s3's (that caught us out!).

This latest issue though, has us completely lost. The cluster builds and the bootstrap does its work, and finally destroys itself, letting the master nodes take over the grunt work. They eventually fail, near the end of the build with the following error:

"the cluster operator image-registry is not available"

There are some interesting observations from the log files, such as:
level=info msg=Cluster operator image-registry Progressing is True with Error: Progressing: Unable to apply resources: unable to sync storage configuration: AccessDenied: Access Denied
level=info msg=Progressing: \tstatus code: 403, request id: WAKY0VN0G4SYMCGD, host id: 4q8tIjVC7fZTu8zQ3PxWPGvU33LG2aHvWhecWyR5T3KNHIFZxlmjrplH+3Zal8Gmb63dRRN9kGSDo/mzKKkbYA==
level=info msg=NodeCADaemonProgressing: The daemon set node-ca is deployed
level=error msg=Cluster operator image-registry Degraded is True with Unavailable: Degraded: The deployment does not exist
level=info msg=Cluster operator ingress EvaluationConditionsDetected is False with AsExpected:
level=info msg=Cluster operator insights ClusterTransferAvailable is False with NoClusterTransfer: no available cluster transfer
level=info msg=Cluster operator insights Disabled is False with AsExpected:
level=info msg=Cluster operator insights SCAAvailable is True with Updated: SCA certs successfully updated in the etc-pki-entitlement secret
level=info msg=Cluster operator network ManagementStateDegraded is False with :
level=error msg=Cluster initialization failed because one or more operators are not functioning properly.
level=error msg=The cluster should be accessible for troubleshooting as detailed in the documentation linked below,
level=error msg=https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/support/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-installations.html
level=error msg=The 'wait-for install-complete' subcommand can then be used to continue the installation
level=error msg=failed to initialize the cluster: Cluster operator image-registry is not available
" installID=8fttkm5k
time="2023-07-20T19:11:10Z" level=debug msg="no additional log fields found" installID=8fttkm5k
time="2023-07-20T19:11:10Z" level=error msg="failed due to install error" error="exit status 6" installID=8fttkm5k
time="2023-07-20T19:11:10Z" level=fatal msg="runtime error" error="exit status 6"
Suggesting that potentially something within the cluster does not have access to the PVC it requires.

Its all very difficult to troubleshoot, since I can't run oc login commands from our bastion where we run the rosa CLI, because its not in a state to receive setup commands, and I have no way as yet to ssh across to the master node. We are seemingly completely blocked, spending hours upon hours on redhat/aws/google/stack sites trying to resolve.

Any ideas would be great!

- Darren

Our company has a policy that denies all aws services from roles by default, we have whitelisted this to no avail.

We have also added all of the pre-requisite egress proxies to our aws account.

I am still getting an email from redhat saying that one of the routes is unavailable that might be the issue, but I can't see which route it would but, as it unhelpfully doesnt say!